# java loop to repeat program

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am extremely new to java I am in my second week in classes or so--

I need my program to keep going or exit according to the user. It is a payroll calculation and I want the end to say "Do you want to continue (y/n)" I want Y to repeat my entire program of questions and no to end program. I am using Jgrasp and I am very very new. I am assuming it needs a loop and I am not totally sure, I just got this to run and compile correctly-- it runs correctly for me so it is a good start and I am hoping to get help on how to do this as I am seeing a ton of different ways and different programs for it. thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculations {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double Regpay;
        double Payperhour;
        int HoursAweek;
        double Pay;
        double OvertimeHours;
        double OvertimePay;
        double Dependants;
        double SocSecTax;
        double FederalTax;
        double StateTax;
        int UnionDues;
        double AllTaxes;
        double FinalPay;
        String playAgain;

        System.out.print("Enter your pay per hour:");
        Payperhour = reader.nextDouble ();

        System.out.print("Enter your regular Hours a week:");
        HoursAweek = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your overtime hours:");
        OvertimeHours = reader.nextDouble();

        Regpay = Payperhour * HoursAweek;

        OvertimePay = OvertimeHours * 1.5 * Payperhour;

        Pay = OvertimePay + Regpay;

        SocSecTax = Pay * .06;

        FederalTax = Pay * .14;

        StateTax = Pay * .05;

        UnionDues = 10;

        AllTaxes = SocSecTax + FederalTax + StateTax + UnionDues; 

        FinalPay = Pay -= AllTaxes;

        System.out.println("Your pay this week will be " +FinalPay);

        {


            System.out.println("How many Dependants:");
            Dependants = reader.nextInt();

            if (Dependants >= 3) {
                Dependants = Pay + 35;
                System.out.println("Your Pay is:" +Dependants);
            } else if(Dependants < 3) {
                System.out.println("Your Pay is:" +Pay);
            }

        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea with your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculations{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        double Regpay;
        double Payperhour;
        int HoursAweek;
        double Pay;
        double OvertimeHours;
        double OvertimePay;
        double Dependants;
        double SocSecTax;
        double FederalTax;
        double StateTax;
        int UnionDues;
        double AllTaxes;
        double FinalPay;
        String playAgain;
        int runAgain = 1;

        while (runAgain == 1) {


            System.out.print("Enter your pay per hour:");
            Payperhour = reader.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter your regular Hours a week:");
            HoursAweek = reader.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter your overtime hours:");
            OvertimeHours = reader.nextDouble();

            Regpay = Payperhour * HoursAweek;

            OvertimePay = OvertimeHours * 1.5 * Payperhour;

            Pay = OvertimePay + Regpay;

            SocSecTax = Pay * .06;

            FederalTax = Pay * .14;

            StateTax = Pay * .05;

            UnionDues = 10;

            AllTaxes = SocSecTax + FederalTax + StateTax + UnionDues;

            FinalPay = Pay -= AllTaxes;

            System.out.println("Your pay this week will be " + FinalPay);
            {


                System.out.println("How many Dependants:");
                Dependants = reader.nextInt();

                if (Dependants >= 3) {
                    Dependants = Pay + 35;
                    System.out.println("Your Pay is:" + Dependants);
                } else if (Dependants < 3) {

                    System.out.println("Your Pay is:" + Pay);
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Again???  Press 1 to run again and 0 to exit");
            runAgain = reader.nextInt();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Brina-Ann if this solves your problem please click the check mark next to the answer, I am glad I could help you!

Comment: This is IT, this is exactly what I needed, you nailed it on the head. I am still super super super new at this, I am hoping to become someone who can answer these questions as well. Lifesaver!!! thank you for teaching me this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide for you..

You can create a method for the transaction.

```
//Place this on your main method
do{
   //call the method
    transaction();  
   //ask if the user wants to repeat the program
   System.out.print("Do you want to continue (y/n)");
   input = reader.nextLine(); 
}while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
```

---

```
public void transaction(){
   //your transaction code here.. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief idea of how to do this:

```
String choice = "y";

while(true) {
    //Take input
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue (y/n)?");
    choice = reader.nextLine();

    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) break;
    //else do your work.
}
```

You can also sue `do-while` to get what you want. You may need to make some changes but then that is the entire idea. It is just a hint.